# What is icu4c and is it necessary to add to PATH?

Tags: node.js, npm, path, homebrew, zshrc

After using Homebrew to install node I got a statement that said

> ```
> If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH, run:
> echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
> echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
> ```

What is icu4c and is it necessary to add to PATH?